# If Matches functions in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out the formula for my work.  I have contract values for ear service unit per month and it renew in different months in a year with different values.  I am looking a formula that If I done the service in particular month ("YES") then sum the value based on "YES" and that months unit value, if "NO" then should not sum the unit value.

Hope I am clear.

Thank you for your valuable suggestions with formula.

[image]

Regards
Yusuf

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried so far and what result is it giving you? Check out "[ask]" and also how to create a [mcve]. (Also, see the [tour] and you'll earn your first badge!)

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the reason why `SUMIFS()` has been invented:

[image]

The formula states:

- Sum the values of column B, from B2 to B7.
- The criteria to keep in mind, are the values in C column, from C2 to C7.
- The value against which to check the criteria, is D3.

Comment: Sorry, not this formula which I am expecting.  I have many service units, each unit have AMC value with different months and I am renewing the AMC each year with different value.  If I do service each unit and if that comes under before renewal month then sum with old AMC vallue if that falls under after renewed month then take the value of after renewal.  (my screenshot of the data sheet can give the clarity to understand).  Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question, explaining why a `SUMIFS()` cannot solve your issue.

Comment: you can do that with the sumifs function, just add a second criteria for the renewalDate and month.